# url encode web service

Tags: web-services, urlencode

Good morning,
I have to convert a string in a url string with hex code.
I found many webapps that makes this but i need to find a web service call like:

```
https://urlencode.com/<string>
```

and it response with the string encoded.

example:

- call: https://urlencode.com/Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
- response: Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F51.0.2704.79%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edge%2F14.14393

do you know something or i have to make the code manually?

Comment: Well, you'll have to url encode the string to call the url encoder service, so I think the world could end...

Comment: that was so funny :D